# Clean git references recursively on a folder

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new to git so maybe this is a basic question but I have not found a way to do what I need, and I don't discard a wrong understanding. We have a Bitbucket server where we are sending or code. I am working on a Windows 10 box and the command line git client.

I created a repository for some different programs but some of them include code obtained from github. As it was obtained using `git clone <url>` it keeps the references of the original repository (as I can see running `git remote -v` on the specific folder).

I have tried to incorporate all the content to our local repository with the following commands but only my parts where incorporated.

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin <localURL>
git push -u origin master
```

I have seen there are plenty of references to folders in gitignore files, I suppose they are preventing it to be uploaded.

Is there a way to delete recursively all the references to git in a path so I can start from a clean folder?

Comment: You sure you don't want to use a submodule instead, to keep the possibility of updating that submodule directly from github at a later date? If you want to only maintain a snapshot of the version you cloned of those libraries then the answer below here will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the `.git` folder in your working directory

Comment: I was hoping for a git command that could do things recursivelly, but this one worked. I had to remove all the .git folders in the structure.

Comment: there are no such command. that's the best way I can give.. :)